# JavaScript is NOT working when uploaded on Host

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed a website using the text-editor called Brackets which allows me to test run it locally using the browser of my choice. I have a jquery plugin for image sliding in my index.html file, and it works perfectly when I test it on my local computer. But when I upload it to Arvixe (web host), it doesn't seem to work. The html elements with their respective css are shown,  but images are halted (instead of sliding).

Here is the piece of code that does not work:

```
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

$(function () {
     $("#test-slider").responsiveSlides({

    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    before: function () {
      $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
    },
    after: function () {
      $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
    }
  });

});
```

Also, the script files are accessed directly (e.g. src="script.js").  When I debug the line with: `$("#test-slider")`, it says that it is `an unexpected identifier`.

Here is a pick of the whole jscript on the bottom of my index.html file:

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6T11.png)

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console for errors? eg, for Google Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en

Comment: check for errors in browser dev tools console and make sure resource file paths are correct in dev tools network tab

Comment: Check all your paths and make sure they are correct and relative to the site root

Comment: Please post your html, css and javascript.

Comment: Check the path of the linked script and make sure it's relative, not absolute (e.g. it should be "/Scripts/myFile.js" instead of "http://localhost:8080/Scripts/myFile.js").

Comment: Thank you for submitting your support. I've updated the post with some code

Comment: You still haven't told if there are errors in the console. If you don't know how to open the console, see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337

Comment: Yes, there are errors. When i debug the line with: $("#test-slider")...., it says that it is an unexpected identifier.

Comment: Did you uploaded the lib that handle `responsiveSlider()` ? As it's not a native jQuery method. Paste all the content of your JS file and the error the console output please.

Comment: You said that you were accessing scripts "directly". Did you also ensure case sensitivity between your filename and your script calls (e.g. if your filename was script.js, did you make sure you referenced it as script.js and not something such as Script.js?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen because of a not valid jQuery path.
Try to put jQuery CDN between your `<head></head>` tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```